# Woocommerce lost password redirection going to wordpress forget password but not to my custom forget password page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The Link to the forget password in woocommerce error message is not redirecting to my custom page but going to wordress default forget password page. I need to change that to redirect to my custom page like "site_url/my-account/lost-password".[image] is there any hook to change the redirection of lost password in woocomerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Check my screenshot from there you can change it.

https://www.screencast.com/t/bNKTJTu4A

I have uploaded screenshot here as well

[image]

**Option 2 :**

```
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url',  'wdm_lostpassword_url', 10, 0 );
 function wdm_lostpassword_url() {
  return site_url('/customslug');
 }
```

**Option 3**

This for the specific error message

```
add_filter('login_errors', 'login_error_message', 99, 2);

function login_error_message($error) {
    //check if that's the error you are looking for
    $pos = strpos($error, 'ERROR');
    $pos2 = strpos($error, 'The password field is empty.');
    if (is_int($pos) && $pos2 == '') {
        //its the right error so you can overwrite it
        $error = "ERROR: Invalid username or password. <a href=" . get_the_permalink(2) . "> Lost your password?</a>"; // instead of 2 you can put your page id or slug
    }
    return $error;
}
```

Comment: Than we need to take the help of actions

Comment: thanks, I had tried all these hooks to change url but it is not working on woocomerce error messages